# Como posso escrever valores na memória de outro processo?

Tags: c#, processo

Eu tenho o endereço de memória, o processo e o valor.

```
// Processo
var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("ePSXe").FirstOrDefault();

// Endereço
IntPtr addr = new IntPtr(0x00A66E11);

// Valor
var val = 0x63;
```

Agora como que faço para escrever este valor na memória do outro processo?

Comment: Vale lembrar que você não vai conseguir escrever nos endereços de memória de outro processo em c#, especialmente se houver mais de um processo rodando no Runtime .NET (CLR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione estes métodos:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hProcess);
```

Flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VMOperation = 0x00000008,
    VMRead = 0x00000010,
    VMWrite = 0x00000020,
    DupHandle = 0x00000040,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}
```

Com isto posso implementar um método para simplificar:

```
public static void WriteMem(Process p, IntPtr address, long v)
{
    var hProc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, (int)p.Id);
    var val = new byte[] { (byte)v };

    int wtf = 0;
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, address, val, (UInt32)val.LongLength, out wtf);

    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

Desta forma posso utilizar:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("ePSXe").FirstOrDefault();

    WriteMem(p, new IntPtr(0x00A66DB9), 99);
}
```

Referencias em inglês:

- [WriteProcessMemory (Kernel32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writeprocessmemory)
- [WriteProcessMemory function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)